# ListView Items Loses Position on OverScroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview which inflates a layout with views in that layout. My Adapter successfully adds each item to its appropriate position when first created. However when the listview is scrolled, the items in the listview behaves oddly by sometimes losing its postion in the listview and sometimes not, I am unsure as what causes the behavior exactly. I did notice that whenever I overscroll the listview, the behavior happens again. To better explain the behavior, once the listview is scrolled or overscrolled, or even scrolled at a very "fast" rate, the listview scrolls past the last item as if another item was below it. Once I try to scroll back to the last item, the listview allows me to scroll only to the last item in the listview (as if the last item is the only item in the listview) then it does not allow me to scroll at all. Here is my adapter

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        positionHolder = position;
        Log.i("Position", "" + position);

        if(convertView == null) {

            try {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
                postLayout = convertView;

                viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                viewHolder.addToCalVF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        ((ViewFlipper)view).showNext();
                        Log.i("VIEWFLIPPERVF", viewHolder.addToCalVF.toString());
                    }
                });


                viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                viewHolder.unameTV.setText(viewContent.get(index));
                viewHolder.unameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Profile.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        String username =((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                        in.putExtra("username", username);
                        Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.fillSpace = (TextView)postLayout.findViewById(R.id.posthelpSpace);
                viewHolder.fillSpace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        View relayout = lv.getChildAt(position);
                        viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                        String username = viewHolder.unameTV.getText().toString();

                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Profile.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        in.putExtra("username", username);
                        Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });




                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postProfPic);
                DisplayImageOptions options = initiateDisplayImageOptions();
                viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        View relayout = lv.getChildAt(position);
                        viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                        String username = viewHolder.unameTV.getText().toString();

                        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                Profile.class);
                        // sending pid to next activity
                        in.putExtra("username", username);
                        Log.i("Username", "" + username);

                        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                        startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                    }
                });

                ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
                initImageLoader(getActivity());
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 1), viewHolder.image, options);








                viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(viewContent.get(index + 3));


                testText = viewHolder.eventTitle;
                viewHolder.eventImage = (ImageView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 4), viewHolder.eventImage, options);


                viewHolder.likesTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.likesTV);
                viewHolder.likesTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 5));

                viewHolder.planToAttendTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.planToAttendTV);
                viewHolder.planToAttendTV.setText(viewContent.get(index + 6));

                viewHolder.addressTV = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postLocationTV);
                viewHolder.addressTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 7));
                viewHolder.addressTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarButton);
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setText(viewContent.get(index + 2));
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Calendar startCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                        startCal.setTime(new Date());
                        startCal.set(STARTYEARS.get(position), STARTMONTHS.get(position), STARTDAYS.get(position), STARTHOURS.get(position), STARTMINS.get(position));


                        Calendar endCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                        endCal.setTime(new Date());
                        endCal.set(ENDYEARS.get(position), ENDMONTHS.get(position), ENDDAYS.get(position), ENDHOURS.get(position), ENDMINS.get(position));

                        String id = Double.toString(EventUtils.assignName());

                        View relayout = lv.getChildAt(position);
                        viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                        title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();

                        addEvent(id, title, startCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis(), position);

                        viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                        Log.i("VIEWFLIPPER", viewHolder.addToCalVF.toString());

                    }
                });

                viewHolder.addToCalConfirm = (TextView) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarConfirmedButton);
                viewHolder.addToCalConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        View relayout = lv.getChildAt(position);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF = (ViewFlipper) relayout.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarVF);
                        viewHolder.addToCalVF.showNext();

                        viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) relayout.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                        title = viewHolder.eventTitle.getText().toString();
                        DeleteCalendarEntry(EVENTIDS.get(position), title);


                    }
                });

                viewHolder.postImageVF = (ViewFlipper) postLayout.findViewById(R.id.postBackgroundHolderVF);


                index = index + 8;



            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag();
        }
        return postLayout;
    }
```

I do have a getCount and getItem method in the adapter that appropriately returns the correct data. I saw that there are many problems that can/will happen when trying to implement a listview in android. How do I have a stable, reliable listview adapter that I can count on the function the same way each time (what do I have to add so that this problem can stop)?

Comment: on this line ` viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag();` you are not updating the views at all. Is it something that you expect?

Comment: @hoomi no. I thought that was all I had to do, to update the views should I add after viewHolder = (ViewHolder) postLayout.getTag(); each view and set the tag to the viewHolder's tag?

Comment: You still need to update your views after you get the viewHolder. for example `viewHolder.textView.setText(position+"");`

Comment: @hoomi this still doesnt stop the behavior

Comment: @superuserdo, hoomi is right, you shouldn't set anything to your views inside `if(convertView==null)`. That's for setting the views, not values. Put all the settings (including listeners, ...) outside the main if-else. Inside the `if`, only inflate the views.

Comment: first help :do not set any value in `(convertView == null)` assign any listener and setText and ... after else condition. in convertView just save your views into viewholder.

Comment: @hoomi Your advice fixed it! Thanks, however if I am not to set the click listeners in the if else statement, then how am i supposed to set them? Now I get null pointers when trying to set the onClick listeners outside of the if-else statement.